# Convergence of sequence without epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have one question, very easy I think:
In another task I want to deal with a countale number of "epsilons" in the definition of the convergence of a sequence. So, can I express convergence of the sequence in the following way: $a_n\rightarrow a$ iff

$\forall_{K>0}\exists_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{n\ge N}\,\,|a_n-a|<\frac{1}{K}$?

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to the $\epsilon ,N$ definition.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I thought.

Comment: And the proof of the equivalence follows from the [Archimedean property](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields) of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Note that this is an important technique to cut down the use of AC in real analysis to just DC (dependent choice) or CC (countable choice), so it is not an idle observation.